# contact with moderators

Tags: support

I am not sure how else to get in contact with moderators so I ask my question here.

One of my questions ("Antonym(ic) definitions of a phenomenon by its lack of property), or perhaps an answer to my question got a strange comment from "Agent Smith":

"Fizz, tickle, tickle, tickle. Laughing?!  Run home, lil child! Jokes aside, wicked comment! – Agent Smith".

I found the administration of this site is usually quite rigorous. Do you really allow these types comments?

Or perhaps the problem is my lack of understanding that it may be some kind of compliment?

Answer (score 1):

Comment deleted. Sorry it escaped my attention - Geoffrey Thomas.